# IIS 7, Multiple Web Sites, Host Headers, and Wildcard Subdomains

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008

I have a need to support multiple websites on a single IIS 7 server. One of these websites needs to be able to support wildcard subdomains. I was hoping to use host headers for this approach but am thinking this is not possible. The site that requires wildcard subdomains won't let me use *.site.com in the host header and therefore won't respond to subdomain requests unless i set it to listen blindly on port 80. If I have that site listen blindly on port 80, it seems my other sites will not work.

It's completely plausible I'm missing a step. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: shouldn't this be on server fault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give each separate website its own IP address and configure IIS to listen based on IP address rather than `Host` header.

Then, any single website with multiple or wildcard subdomains but at a separate IP will work with IIS listening to all incoming requests on that IP.

Comment: yup this is what i ended up doing.

Comment: Observation: Strangely, this IP setting seems to be completely benign for me. I setup a test site with a simple text page, and it seems not matter what IP I bind it to, it always renders. Other sites, however, only refresh properly if set to "*". Makes no sense to me. :(

Answer (score 0):

Just use site.com not *.site.com

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is IIS doesnt support this. Im assuming the next best option is to use URL rewriting and set a rewrite in the global rules (not per site). I've been using IIRF with good results, and it is free. Version 2.x now has a server-level global re-write rules, then each site has its own per-site rewrite rules. I'd set something to redirect (or maybe even rewrite) *.domain.com to a fixed sub, like www.domain.com. Or even get creative and pass it as a folder like domain.com/subdomain .

Not optimal solutions, but should work.

I'm really surprised we cant get iis to do regular wildcards on hostheaders. Seems pretty basic fucntionality.